Chrome Devtools Protocoll Network.getResponseBody() not working
i'm using a Python library called Nodriver to do web automation, this library is based on CDP and i implemented a network monitor which analyzes incoming requests, select the one for which i want to look at the response, wait for it to finish loading and then get its response body.
This is the script:
    def request_handler(event: cdp.network.RequestWillBeSent, request_ids: list[cdp.network.RequestId]):
       """track AJAX request used for double check before paying bet""" 
       if event.request.url != "https://webapi.microgame.it/v2/Sport/Schedule/live": return
       print(event.request_id, event.request.url)
       request_ids.append(event.request_id)

    ## network monitor
    failed_response_ids: list[cdp.network.RequestId] = []
    response_ids: list[cdp.network.RequestId] = []
    request_ids: list[cdp.network.RequestId] = []
    await page.send(cdp.network.enable())
    page.add_handler(cdp.network.RequestWillBeSent, lambda event: request_handler(event, request_ids))
    page.add_handler(cdp.network.LoadingFinished, lambda event: response_ids.append(event.request_id) if event.request_id in request_ids else None )
    page.add_handler(cdp.network.LoadingFailed, lambda event: failed_response_ids.append(event.request_id) if event.request_id in request_ids else None )

I'm using this method on different websites and different requests. but this one in particular [request link][1] gives me trouble  when retrieving the responnse body trough
response_id = response_ids[-1]
response = await page.send(cdp.network.get_response_body(response_id))

I want to specify that my script works for all the other websites and request, so i'm assuming it must be something in this specific request.
This are the request/response headers, as you can see it is a cross origin request made to an api and the response should be a json dict containing the data i'm searching for.
request headers:
GET /v2/Sport/LiveOdds/all-248/all/principali_live/all HTTP/2
Host: webapi.microgame.it
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:124.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/124.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://www.playmatika.it/
Content-Type: text/plain
Origin: https://www.playmatika.it
Connection: keep-alive
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-GPC: 1
TE: trailers

response headers:
HTTP/2 200 
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
content-encoding: gzip
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.playmatika.it
content-length: 26450
cache-control: max-age=8
date: Sat, 04 May 2024 14:02:59 GMT
vary: Accept-Encoding
server-timing: cdn-cache; desc=HIT
server-timing: edge; dur=1
mg-akamai-debug: Controller Sport (TOP Live)
vary: Referer
vary: Referer
server-timing: ak_p; desc="1714831379410_34608873_1111684016_31_4878_8_0_21";dur=1
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

I also tried usging cdp.Network.replayXHR() but the request has sttaus code of 200 and the website which fires it is able to retrieve the response and update their websites. So using replayXHR() did nothing.
[1]: https://webapi.microgame.it/v2/Sport/Schedule/live
